# Java basics about generics and reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am having a basic java question as I recently decided to dig into the language (I have been working exclusively with C++ for a long time and decided to expand my horizons a bit).

Assuming that I have a class called BankAccount and I try to create and object in my main, what is the difference between:

```
Class baCls = BankAccount.class;
```

and

```
Class<BankAccount> baCls = BankAccount.class;
```

What does the baCls hold in each of the cases and what is the compiler output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases `baCls` is a reference to the class `BankAccount`

The generic adds a compile time check but has no impact at runtime.

You can see the bytecode generated if you use `javap -c -p` or a byte code viewer in your IDE.

Comment: Aha, I understand, thank you.
So besides that there is no difference and baCls can be used in the same way in both cases in the program, is that correct?

Comment: @Cooli the main trick comping from C++ is that Java only have primitives and references. There is no other types (except `void`) which is why there is no special symbols to show you its a reference.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I think it will take me some time until I get a bit unstuck from the C++ concepts.

Comment: @Cooli some of the things you have to do in C++, Java just doesn't need like `#ifdef` macros and `.h` header files.

Answer (score 0):

*Peter Lawrey's answer addresses your specific question, but I think that it is missing an important fact that the second case provides additional, invaluable information to the compiler.*

The difference is that the first case is a *raw type*:

```
Class baCls = BankAccount.class;
     ^ Missing type parameters.
```

There are (at least) two consequences of this (which are general consequences of using raw types):

1. You can't invoke producer methods like `Class.nextInstance()` method and assign the result to a reference of type `BankAccount` without a cast:

   ```
   Class baCls = BankAccount.class;
   BankAccount instance = (BankAccount) baCls.newInstance(/* required args */);
   ```

   However, you don't need the cast in the second case, because it is known that the `nextInstance` method will return an instance of `BankAccount`:

   ```
   Class<BankAccount> baClsSafe = BankAccount.class;
   BankAccount instance = baCls.newInstance(/* req args */);
   ```
2. You lose type safety if you are putting these into collections. For instance:

   ```
   Class baCls = BankAccount.class;
   List<Class<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(baCls);  // Compiles fine.
   ```

   This appears fine, but you get a runtime exception later if you assume that the elements in the list are of the correct type:

   ```
   for (Class<String> clazz : list) {
     String instance = clazz.newInstance();  // ClassCastException.
   }
   ```

   because `instance` is actually an instance of `BankAccount` (assuming that has a zero-args constructor).

   In the second case, you would never be able to add this item to the list in the first place:

   ```
   Class<BankAccount> baCls = BankAccount.class;
   List<Class<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(baCls);  // Compiler error.
   ```

I would recommend that you read up about raw types, e.g. in the [generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), as well as in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 23 "Don't use raw types in new code".